# Não consigo gravar as informações no Banco de dados (PYTHON\MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, python

Estou tentando inserir essa query, mas ele n registra na tabela do MySql, porem eu percebo q ele esta acessando certo, pois sempre usa uma posição do 'cod' que é primaryKey

*quando uso a string no SQL do banco de dados ele insere normalmente

`bd = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="medicbd")
cursor = bd.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'paciente' ('nome', 'nascimento', 'telefone', 'celular','cpf','estado','cidade') VALUES('ghfhgf','04-06-1997','359920556','0569875468','021465821','mg','kj')")
cursor.close()
bd.close()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou o `bd.commit()`. Basicamente, os dados não entram no banco no momento em que você executa a query. É necessário dar o commit para realizar as ações de fato.

```
bd = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="medicbd")
cursor = bd.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'paciente' ('nome', 'nascimento', 'telefone', 'celular','cpf','estado','cidade') VALUES('ghfhgf','04-06-1997','359920556','0569875468','021465821','mg','kj')")
bd.commit()
cursor.close()
bd.close()
```